# Passing more than one value to a parameter

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have been able to pass one value to a parameter in crystal reports. However, I am now tasked with passing more than one value to a parameter. I want to query a an sql server database and pass the query results to the parameter. If the results of the query are greater than one, all these should be captured by the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do is

1. Go to Select Expert
2. Select the field from data source which has the multiple values
3. From the dropdown, select `is one of`

Also your parameter field should be set to `Allow multiple values = true`

Comment: Could you please help me with the query that i will now use to set the values?

Comment: @OderoEdwin: How can I help you without knowing what you trying to achive/which tables you using and which fields?